# Attemptng to sync combo boxes in Access 2010 yields dialog box

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

I have a simple, one-table database, the one table called tbl.Volunteers with information about our volunteers.

I'm creating a form called frmVolunteerManagement with just two combo boxes so far: cmbLastName and cmbFirstName.

When I select an entry from cmbLastName I want cmbFirstName to be limited to only those who have that last name.

I've tried a dozen or more solutions from various sources and those that don't kick up either a compile error or syntax error give me a dialog box asking me to Enter Parameter Value for fldFirstName.

Here's the code I've tried most recently, borrowed directly from Microsoft's help page:

`Me.cmbFirstName.RowSource = "SELECT fldFirstName FROM tblVolunteers WHERE LastName = Me.cmbLastName ORDER BY fldFirstName"`

I'm assuming that the problem is with the definition of my form but it's pretty much default except I did set the Record Source to tblVolunteers.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: `Me.cmbFirstName.RowSource = "SELECT fldFirstName FROM tblVolunteers WHERE LastName = '" & Me.cmbLastName & "' ORDER BY fldFirstName"`

Comment: Are these UNBOUND controls used to input filter criteria?  Regardless, consider one combobox with a RowSource that concatenates name parts: `SELECT ID, fldLastName & ", " & fldFirstName AS FullName FROM tblVolunteers;`

Comment: I get the same result, a dialog box wanting me to Enter Parameter Value, fld.LastName  
  
I tried changing fldLastName to [tblVolunteers].[fldLastName] etc. and got the dropdown to work but only the ID of the selected record displayed after selecting.

Comment: what you are doing is called cascading comboboxes so you can combine that with Access and find youtube videos.  When you see the id it means in the combobox format properties the id columns width is not 0.  To fix that, if you have 3 columns like id, columnname, b then under format properties set columns to 3 and set column widths to 0,1,0 Elsewhere in the properties, make sure bound column matches the id column. in my example that is 1

Comment: Still ain't working.

Comment: Still ain't working.  

Column Count is 3  
Column Widths is 1";1";1" (this done by MS: I didn't have to change it.  

What I get is a dialog box asking for fldLastName; I enter my last name and I get another dialog box asking for fldFirstName; enter my first name and now I can select one from 544 volunteers named Ehinger, Michael (there being 544 records in the table.  

I tried replacing fldLastName with [tblVolunteers].[fldLastName}, etc. as MS formats it and I get the same thing except the dialog box asks for [tblVolunteers].[fldLastName] instead of fldLastName.  

Continued . . .

Comment: As for Youtube videos,  been over them as I have every other source I can find; they all give variations on the same as I posted above; and the ones that don't generate either a syntax error or a compile error give me the same results as above.  

I'm thinking there's something more basic wrong here.